# Why there is no journalctl in my centos 6.6 box and how to install/enable it?

Tags: centos, journalctl

I have various environment on CentOS, the hosts on CentOS7+ all come with journalctl command so if I need to view system log I can do so.

However on another box it is CentOS6.6, I get error of the command is not found.

Can anyone enlighten on how to check log in CentOS6.6 without journalctl? or how to install/enable journalctl?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `journalctl` in CentOS 6 because it's too old.

CentOS 6 was released in 2010, and systemd was first released in 2011.

You can find system logs in various files in the `/var/log` directory. By default most system logs will be in `/var/log/messages` with certain security-related logs appearing instead in `/var/log/secure`.